# How to send valid HTTPS requests to a web service via SslStream and TcpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, ssl, https

I'm essentially attempting to setup a HTTPS client I can use for automated testing APIs and other web services I'm developing. I'm familiar with using sockets, but not so much with using SSL/TLS in code. I've started by attempting to setup a client that sends an HTTP request to google.com with the following header: `GET / HTTP/1.1`

The idea is to receive a basic HTTP response from Google, via an encrypted connection of course. This is really easy when using unencrypted HTTP - I can even telnet into google over port 80 and enter `GET / HTTP/1.1` and I receive a nice HTTP response header and HTML payload. Implementing the C/C# code for making unencrypted HTTP requests is also not very difficult.  It's SSL that is giving me a difficult time.

Using the code below (full sample found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3), which is an almost identical implementation to what is provided by MSDN for reference, I can successfully connect to `google.com` and validate the server certificate:

```
        // Create a TCP/IP client socket.
        // machineName is the host running the server application.
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(machineName, 443);
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
        // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(),
            false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
            null
            );
        // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
```

The issue is when the following code executes, the ReadMessage(sslStream) instruction hangs, as in I don't receive a response for a very long time, and when the response finally comes in it is an empty string:

```
        // Encode a test message into a byte array.
        // Signal the end of the message using the "<EOF>".
        byte[] messsage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.1<EOF>");
        // Send hello message to the server. 
        sslStream.Write(messsage);
        sslStream.Flush();
        // Read message from the server.
        string serverMessage = ReadMessage(sslStream);
        Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", serverMessage);
```

Therefore, I'm unable to receive the HTTP response I was looking for (or anything at all) when I make this request over a secure socket connection. The idea in the long run is to start using this client to send customized HTTP requests to my own APIs and web services, but I certainly cannot do that if I cannot even get a generic response from google.com.  Does anyone have an idea why the ReadMessage() function is timing out or otherwise providing no response? The sample code seems very straightforward so I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "<EOF>" will break the HTTP request rendering it unparseable by a web server, what is it?  GET should be terminated with \r\n

Comment: <EOF> was suggested by the comments in the referenced code from MSDN. I'll tried replacing it with \r\n but I experience the same behavior.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I think the correct terminator is "\r\n\r\n"  not just \r\n.

Comment: @anthonyterra you are correct - the reason is that the first \r\n only gets you to where form data would be added to the HTTP header. Adding another \r\n signals that form data has already been provided or it isn't to be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that immediately caught my attention is that the Microsoft example does not provide the "count" argument for `sslStream.Write()`, which I believe may be related to your issue. Also note, `ReadMessage()` appears to be a function you have not provided a definition for. Without knowing what `ReadMessage()` is doing specifically, the exact cause of your problem cannot be determined. I modified the provided code for sending a HTTPS request and reading the response. It seems to work fine with sites I've tried thus far.

```
        // Send request
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytes;
        byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("GET https://{0}/  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n", serverName));
        sslStream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
        sslStream.Flush();

        // Read response
        do
        {
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
        } while (bytes == 2048);
```

As a side note, I also noticed `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);` which certainly works for many web services; however, I've had issues with that particular overload when accessing sites that strictly use TLS1.2.  Try `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName,null,SslProtocols.Tls12,false);` if you want to enable support for strictly TLS1.2 agents.